# DB2 The syntax of the string representation of a datetime value is incorrect

Tags: casting, timestamp, db2

We have a staging table that's used to load raw data from our suppliers.

One column is used to capture a time-stamp but its data-type is varchar(265). Data's dirty: about 40% of the time, there is garbage data, otherwise time-stamp data like this

```
2011/11/15 20:58:48.041
```

I have to create a report that filters some dates/timestamps out that column but where I try to cast it, I get an error:

```
db2 => select cast(loadedon as timestamp) from automation

1
--------------------------
SQL0180N  The syntax of the string representation of a datetime value is incorrect.  SQLSTATE=22007
```

What do I need to do in order to parse/cast the timestamp string?

Comment: be aware that this is the same message if you provide a date in the right format, but an illegal value for a part e.g. `'2026-05-31'` is valid `'2026-06-31'` is not (only 30 days in June)

Answer (score 17):

The string format for a [DB2 timestamp](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0211yip/0211yip3.html) is either:

```
'2002-10-20-12.00.00.000000'
```

or

```
'2002-10-20 12:00:00'
```

You have to get your date string in either of these formats.

Also DB2 runs on a 24 hour clock even though the output sometimes uses a 12 hour clock (AM / PM)

So '2002-10-20 14:49:50' For 2:49:50 PM

Or '2002-10-20 00:00:00' For midnight.  Output would be 12:00:00 AM

Comment: @Chris: Then you will have to write a conversion program in a language that also allows for SQL.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you have a lot of garbage data, so firt of all you should check if the data is a valid timestamp in the format you expect ('2011/11/15 20:58:48.041'). We could use a simple solution - just replace all digits with '0' and check the result format:

```
TRANSLATE(timestamp_column,'0','0123456789','0') = '0000/00/00 00:00:00.000'
```

If the format is the expected one, you should convert to DB2 timestamp. In DB2 for iSeries there is a build-in function since V6R1 [TIMESTAMP_FORMAT](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzscatsformat.htm). In your case it will look like that:

```
TIMESTAMP_FORMAT('2011/11/15 20:58:48.041','YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS.NNNNNN')
```

So the solution query combined should look something like that:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN TRANSLATE(timestamp_column,'0','0123456789','0') = '0000/00/00 00:00:00.000'
        THEN TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(timestamp_column,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS.NNNNNN')
        ELSE NULL
    END
FROM
    your_table_with_bad_data
```

#### EDIT

I just saw your comment that provider agreed to clean the data. You could use the solution provided to speed up the process and clean the data by yourself:

```
ALTER your_table_with_bad_data ADD COLUMN clean_timestamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL;

UPDATE your_table_with_bad_data
SET clean_timestamp =
   CASE
        WHEN TRANSLATE(timestamp_column,'0','0123456789','0') = '0000/00/00 00:00:00.000'
        THEN TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(timestamp_column,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS.NNNNNN')
        ELSE NULL
    END;
```